# Setting global tikz options directly vs. inside the 'every picture' style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

The TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a states in the description of the `/tikz/every picture` style on p. 125:

> you should not use `\tikzset` to set options directly. For instance, if you want to use a line width of `1pt` by default, do not try to say `\tikzset{line width=1pt}` at the beginning of your document. This will not work since the line width is changed in many places. Instead, say
>
> \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=1pt}}
>
> This will have the desired effect.

Why does the fact that the line width is changed in many places affect the direct option, but not the same option inside a style?

Comment: `every picture` is pretty much like `\AtBeginDocument` except that  `document` is replaced by `tikzpicture`. So the question is pretty much like whether we should put some macro in the preamble or in `\AtBeginDocument`. And the general answer is that once you know how macros overwrite each others you will know the correct order.

Comment: @Symbol1: I'm afraid I'm rather a noob, and am not familiar with `\AtBeginDocument` and what its advantages are to defining macros in the preamble. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ sets up a default argument set at the start of each *picture*. It takes the advantage of TeX behavior of *nothing is deleted but only overwritten*.

Hence when setting up the TikZ pictureit also sets line width, default color etc. while towards the end of the initialization it executes `every ...` keys.

So very roughly it becomes

```
\tikzset{ line width = 0.3 pt,
          line join = miter, 
          ...,
          every picture, 
          every path,
          every node
          every label
          ...
          }
```

(I'm just guessing the order I didn't check at all).

So there is an order to the `every ...` keys and if any of them include `line width` key it will overwrite the previous ones and that's what is mentioned.

But if only set once then it will always be overwritten by many other keys.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. Are you saying that setting a property inside the `every picture` style has greater priority over setting the same property directly? But if this is what you're saying than what's the purpose of the `every picture` style? Why not make this style obsolete, and then you can set global properties directly without fear that they'll get overwritten by some `every picture` style, because this style is no longer supported by TikZ.

Comment: @EvanAad I think I don't understand your objection. If you don't set them, the defaults survive. If you set something outside the picture then it will be get overwritten *in many places* because they need to be initialized in order to work properly.

Comment: Does writing `\tikzset{line width=1pt}` have any effect?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Before the code inside a `tikzpicture` environment starts executing, a list of options is applied. We shall refer to this option list as the *actual* option list. Different `tikzpicture` environments generally have different actual option lists. The actual option list of a given `tikzpicture` environment is constructed by concatenating four option lists in this order: 1. accumulated Tikzset, 2. default, 3. "every", 4. explicit. These lists are described below.

Comment: 1. The Accumulated Tikzset option list: The accumulated options specified by all the `Tikzset` commands prior to the `tikzpicture` environment. 2. The default option list: The TikZ package comes with a pre-built list of options that are automatically applied to every `tikzpicture` environment.  3. The "every" option list: The options set by the styles `every picture`, `every path`, etc. 4. The explicit option list: The options specified inside the square brackets following the `\begin{tikzpicture}`, i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[<explicit option list>]`.

Comment: Therefore, if you set an option inside a `Tikzset` command, this option will be overwritten if it is also defined in one of the other three option lists: default, "every", or explicit. However, if you set an option as part of an `every picture` style, then the option will be overwritten only if it was redefined inside a higher priority "every" option list, or else explicitly. In particular, since `line width` is a default option, to set it globally you must set it inside an `every picture` style (or an `every path` style, etc.)

Comment: @EvanAad Yes skipping a few technicalities that is indeed the general situation. It might help to note that every path command starts with the initial default settings and then adds `[every path, #1]` such that you can still override the generic settings. This is quite a different way of doing things in other languages, say, in Python, you can't use the same keyword twice but in pgfkeys syntax, the last one wins.

Comment: So now I understand, but this leaves me wondering: suppose I write a new package, `TikZ 2`, that is in every way the same as `TikZ` except that every direct option inside a `\tikzset` command is interpreted as though it was part of an `every picture` style, i.e every `\tikzset{<key>=<value>}` is interpreted as `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={<key>=<value>}}`. Is there any thing that `TikZ` can do that `TikZ 2` can't, or vice versa?

Comment: @EvanAad That's where things get a bit hairy. If you search this site about `pgfkeys` questions some of them are actually on this topic. You can filter key families or you can forward certain keys and forbid the others etc. It is really a full fledged key system. `\tikzset` is only a convenience for skipping the typing of `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, ....}` everytime. Note for example, pgfplots or pgfplotstable or tcolorbox all have their own partial overwriting of the relevant keys to impose their own choices over TikZ.